# Hosting plans that allow more then 1 GB for mysql and easier mod_rewrites?

Tags: mysql, mod-rewrite, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm using godaddy and am thinking of moving to another hosting company that allows easier mod_rewrites and a bigger limit for a mysql database. Does anyone know of a better hosting company that does this?

Answer (score 0):

what is your budget and expectations on uptime and stability?

I recommend a vps like linode.com where you get root access and can install whatever you want.  They have great uptime and stability and performance is as expected from the memory/cpu/disk you are alloted.

there are also extremely cheap solutions like yardvps.com but in my experience these solutions have spotty performance and less stability.

Comment: I'll will like to stay in the price range that I pay for godaddy Deluxe or Ultimate hosting plans

Answer (score 0):

[Inmotion](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/) and [Bluehost](https://www.bluehost.com/) are pretty good.

Comment: I'd stay away from Bluehost. I've seen quite a few sites hosted by them taken down because of bandwidth quotas or some other reason. Also their site uses a low trust SSL certificate from a questionable CA.

Answer (score 0):

Get a VPS with say 1GB dedicated and 2GB Burst RAM. http://www.lowendbox.com. If you can slightly increase the budget (to say $20) - you can get a very reliable XEN VPS with similar specs else openVZ should be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest calling hosting companies and talk to a sales rep. Your situation is uncommon, so avoiding the "package deal" pricing schemes might get you a much better deal that fits better. Limits like 1GB databases are usually just arbitrary price tags set by marketing anyway, a sales rep will be more flexible. They might not bend very far for under $20/month, but it's worth a try.

I'm a big fan of the non-managed VPS hosts like Linode, but wouldn't recommend it unless you really know your way around a web server - installing & configuring all the software, handling kernel upgrades, configuring iptables, disabling root, etc. You could be setting yourself for a lot of problems otherwise.

And assuming "easier mod_rewrites" means easier syntax, see if [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) can do what you need. The only other implication of "easier" I can think of is if your host just forbids them. In that case, just about any other host will be easier.